# Equivalence of derived categories which is not Fourier-Mukai

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, complex-geometry

D. Orlov proved that any equivalence of bounded derived categories *F:D<sup>b</sup>(X) -> D<sup>b</sup>(Y)* is a Fourier-Mukai transform, when *X* and *Y* are smooth projective varieties. Is there any example of such equivalence, which is not a Fourier-Mukai transform (it is not an integral transform)?

Comment: Perhaps you could be a little clearer: do you mean an equivalence of such categories when X and Y are varieties that are not projective?

Comment: He means an example of the equivalence between two derived categories together with the proof that this equivalence doesn't come from a Fourier-Mukai transform, imho.

Comment: Exactly, I am asking for an example of such an equivalence which is not of Fourier-Mukai type.

Comment: Just a sec, as stated, this is nonsense. You're asking for something that contradicts Orlov's result. Maybe you phrased the question inaccurately?

Comment: @Scott: I think he's asking for an equivalence of such categories when X and Y are not smooth projective varieties, with a proof that the equivalence does not come from a Fourier-Mukai.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Schlichting gave an example of two categories of singularities which are derived equivalent but whose K-groups are not isomorphic. Dugger and Shipley (arXiv:0710.3070) expanded on this example and noted that it gives two dga's which are derived equivalent but not by an integral transform.

Otherwise, Lunts and Orlov's [results](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.4187) on uniqueness of enhancements give a large class of triangulated categories for which one might lift exact functors to dg-functors and apply Toen's result.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of a counterexample but I can tell you some more situations in which it is true. Ballard has extended Orlov's result (in *[Equivalences of derived categories of sheaves on quasi-projective schemes](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3148)*) as well as getting a result in this direction for the case of quasi-projective varieties. There is also section 8.3 of Toën's paper *[The homotopy theory of dg-categories and derived Morita theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408337)* which treats DG enhancements but shows that the philosophy of integral transforms and "bimodules" is a very general one.

Comment: I am interested more of the case of compact complex manifolds or analytic spaces. Ballard also poses a similar question in the Introduction of his paper (after theorem 1.4).

Comment: Also, Ben-Zvi, Francis, and Nadler proved an extension of Toen's result to hold for arbitrary perfect stacks.